# iPhone Simulator Screenshot Size Became Small after XCode Update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I updated my Xcode to the latest version and one thing I notice is that the screenshot image dimension size became small.

Before I updated it when I take screenshot using the Simulators built-in "Save Screenshot" function on `iPhone 6 Plus simulator`. I would get `1920 * 1080`, But now the image dimension is only `414 * 736`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Solution 1:** (from Kip's answer)

in Simulator menu uncheck the option **Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale.**

**Solution 2:**

Simulators menu chose Window->Scale->100%. (keyboard shortcut: ⌘1)

Then save screenshot (keyboard shortcut: ⌘S).

Comment: Well, before the update, I could set the Scale size at anything and it still returns the full resolution

Comment: @JayVDiyk In latest Xcode version (7.1) this's way to get biggest screenshot size. If you want 1920 * 1080 after Screenshot use Preview app and "Tools"->"Adjust Size"

Comment: I've found it's the 9.1 simulator that behaves this way, the 9.0 sim will save images at 100%, regardless of sim scale.

Comment: The issue with this is that the simulator may not fit on your screen, meaning you have to keep resizing or fiddling with scroll bars.

Answer (score 30):

Uncheck the option **Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale**.

This will cause the saved screenshots to be in device resolution again, without requiring you to resize the device to the point where you can't see half of it.

Comment: This is THE solution!!

Comment: Good solution, it's not feasible to turn 100% and screen each time. My monitor is not able to fit an iPhone res

Answer (score 3):

You can download the iOS 9.0 or 8.4 Simulator and use it from within XCode 7.1. They save screenshots at the device's native resolution instead of the scaled resolution.

If you want to take screenshots for the iPad Pro (which only runs iOS 9.1), you're stuck having to change back to 100% scale each time. A keyboard shortcut for this is ⌘1, ⌘S, ⌘3

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode 12 select **Prefer Discrete GPU** to fix this.

**File > GPU Selection > Prefer Discrete GPU**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! you saved a lot of my time resizing screenshots because 1px lost.